# org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected character encountered (lex state 9): ''

Tags: java, xml

I am getting the following error while uploading a document having a numeric file name. The error does not occur if the file name contains only letters and no digits. Suppose I am uploading a pdf file having file name `1234.pdf` then its giving the following error:

```
org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected character encountered (lex state 9): '1'
```

Would really appreciate if someone could give me some light on the issue. I have done some google search on this but not able to solve the issue.

Comment: Please post the relevant code and the full stacktrace of the exception